# how to checkout sale price of product in postgresql database for openerp 7

Tags: postgresql, odoo, openerp-7, psql, openerp-8

I want to know following two things:

1. To find the OpenERP table where cost/sale price of product. I have looked in product_product and product_pricelist tables but still cannot find the price.
2. Once it is found, I have a list of new prices of all thse products on a spreadsheet, what SQL statement do I need to write in order to alter the old prices with the new prices.

Comment: i have found it, it is in product_template....  Thanks y'all

Answer (score 1):

1). you can see the cost price and sale price fields in product_template       model, which is many2one in product_product (product_tmpl_id).

2). to update sale price use this sql query,

update product_template set list_price = your_price where id in (
select product_tmpl_id from product_product where default_code = 'default_code_of_product')

the same thing for cost price just change then field name, use "standard_price".

Sale Price = **list_price** and 
Cost Price = **standard_price**.